# Geometry Nodes: Align rotation to vector with fields

Tags: geometry-nodes

The align rotation to vector node was removed in the 3.0 alpha and I was wondering what the math was behind this node to achieve the same result in Geometry Nodes with fields.

Comment: Hello ! The nodes are slowly getting added back into the 3.0 branch, which is still in alpha. We are trying to avoid Q&As about unreleased versions because most problems are just 1 or 2 patches away from being solved